# How do I inherit private member variables and public functions from another file?

Tags: c++, file, inheritance, compilation

I'm trying to call a function **insertBack(newVal)** from **container.cpp** inside the **Stack.cpp** file, but the compiler throws an error: identifier "insertBack" is undefined. Also, trying to do the same thing for a variable **n** which is found in the same file but under the private area--the error is the same: identifier "n" is undefined.

This is my first time doing multiple file compilation and inheritance.

**Stack.cpp**

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include "container.h"

Stack::Stack()
{
    container();
}

bool Stack::push(int newVal)
{
    return insertBack(newVal);
}

void Stack::pop()
{
    --n;
}
```

**container.h**

```cpp
#ifndef CONTAINER_H
#define CONTAINER_H

#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class container
{
public:
    container();
    // Postcondition: data member n is initialized to -1 and all elements in the empty arr array are initialized to zero
    bool insertBack(int val);
    //  Precondition: the container object is not full
    // Postcondition: if arr array is not full, n is incremented by 1; returns true with val is inserted at the end of the arr array 
    //                 Otherwise, returns false; the value is not inserted and program execution continues.

private:
    static const int CAPACITY = 10;     // physical size of the arr array or the storage capacity of a container object
    int arr[CAPACITY];          // arr array can store up to CAPACITY  (10 in our case) integers 
    int n;                      // n is used as the subscript for the arr array. n is initialized to -1 for an empty array
                                // Each time a new value is inserted into the arr array, n must first be incremented 
                                // by 1. Since n has been initialized to -1, the first inserted value is stored in arr[0],
                                // and the 2nd inserted value will be in arr[1], etc.  and the nth inserted value will be 
                                // stored in arr[n – 1]. Obviously, n + 1 represents the actual number of elements
                                // stored in the array after n rounds of insertion.         
};

#endif
```

**Stack.h**

```cpp
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Stack
{
public:
    Stack();
    // Postcondition: an empty stack object is created (with n initialized to -1 as in P1)
    bool push(int newVal);
    // Postcondition: if the stack is full, returns false. Otherwise, returns true; also the newVal is pushed onto the stack 
    //                 and the stack size is incremented by 1
    void pop();
    //  Precondition: the Stack must not be empty or this function will not be called
    // Postcondition: the object (an integer value) on top of the Stack is logically popped or deleted,  3) and Stack size is decremented by 1
};

#endif
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In particular, please provide your code as text (not an image link) since image links may break in the future. In order to provide a minimal example, I recommend showing us the relevant contents of `Stack.cpp` along with the relevant parts of `Stack.h` and `container.h`.

Comment: Please edit your post with *text* of the code not pictures.  I tried to help by pasting the image into my IDE, but my IDE doesn't like pictures.

Comment: And now edit it with `Stack.h` please. We need to see how `Stack` relates to `Container`.

Comment: Thank you for converting the picture into text, but please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to ensure that we have all the details needed to understand the problem.

Comment: Where is `insertBack` defined? Nowhere.

Comment: @user253751 i made a mistake and left it out--i've edited the code for the original message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the contents of the `Stack` constructor, I conclude that you want `Stack` to inherit from `container`. `Stack.h` already includes `container.h`, so the `container` class is visible anywhere where `Stack` is visible.

What you have to do is declare the actual inheritance:

```
class Stack : container
```

You will get some compiler errors (for one thing, the container constructor is private), but that's a story for another day.

Comment: A big error on my part; I removed public cause of a misunderstanding when I was reducing the amount of code for this question. I did try:

```class Stack : public container```

before putting up this question: I still did get those two undefined errors, so I reverted my changes. And I made the changes now with your suggestion: the errors still persist.

Comment: @S.Coughing As of right now the only thing that appears to be wrong in your code is the missing inheritance, so this IS the correct answer. I recommend fixing the code up with the inheritance because it's closer to right than what you currently have and asking a new question so as to not invalidate this answer.

Comment: @S.Coughing I owe you a small correction: You're likely getting a different error when you have `Stack` deriving from `container`.  `container::n` is `private` and inaccessible. It needs to be `protected`. There is no `insertBack`, only Zuul. Sorry. Spent my formative years in the 80's. There is only `insertFront`.

Comment: @user4581301 oh alright, i tried compiling the code after making that change, and i got this error: ```'container': base class undefined```. So, I'm guessing there's something else that's wrong, hmm--going to try to figure this out, thanks guys.

Update: just saw your message

Comment: @S.Coughing Make sure that stack.h  has a `#include "container.h"`. Currently that is missing as well.

Comment: I swear it was there when I wrote he answer :)